# All tail-recursive functions other than "rev" need to traverse a list twice?

Tags: functional-programming

From what I've gathered, when implementing a tail-recursive call, the resulting list elements stored in an `acc`(accumulator) variable will actually appear backwards, so the general trend seems to be to reverse it back before returning it from the current function.

This means that if I'm not mistaken, there is a systematic overhead for all high order functions (other than `rev`, obviously) calls in a functional programming language, at least with their imperative counterparts.

Am I missing something here? Isn't this actually pretty terrible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just means that tail-call recursion isn't the be-all and end-all of optimization in functional programming. For one thing, lists themselves are linked lists under the hood and in all languages algorithms on linked lists are somewhat inefficient. For this reason, functional languages typically provide constructs which are closer to imperative arrays for situations in which the programmer needs to deal efficiently with large linear collections. Also, other than in introductory exercises, scenarios in which you build up lists element by element by explicit recursion are relatively rare. Instead, higher-order functions like `map` and `filter` are more commonly used in production code. It becomes a question for compiler or standard library writers how to implement those.

I once was sufficiently curious that I tracked down how SML/NJ implements `map` in their standard library. I was expecting to see it implemented via tail-call recursion using `rev` in the way that you described. Instead, they do this:

```
fun map f = let
      fun m [] = []
    | m [a] = [f a]
    | m [a, b] = [f a, f b]
    | m [a, b, c] = [f a, f b, f c]
    | m (a :: b :: c :: d :: r) = f a :: f b :: f c :: f d :: m r
      in
    m
      end
```

A non-tail call recursive version that cuts down by a factor of 4 the function-call overhead implicit in the naïve recursive approach. They probably considered the idea of using a tail-call recursive approach but then rejected it because they didn't want the performance hit of two passes.

A final remark, every language other than perhaps C has features that make one ask "isn't this actually pretty terrible?" from an efficiency point of view. Python -- every object has a header which gives its type and size -- isn't that actually pretty terrible? etc. Languages involve trade-offs. In the big picture, functional languages are languages which try to optimize developer time at the expense of execution time. Modern computers are blindingly fast -- why not use some of that speed to implement languages which allow you to code more concisely at a higher level of abstraction? For hard-core numerical analysis maybe not the best trade-off, but for many problem domains it is a good idea.